# Is there a difference between using Svelte with Nativescript and "Svelte native"?

Tags: nativescript, svelte, svelte-native

Is there a difference between using Svelte with Nativescript and "Svelte native" ?

If yes, what is the most significant difference in practice ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Svelte native", if you mean [this](https://svelte-native.technology/), it uses NativeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Svelte Native is a new approach to building mobile applications using NativeScript. Where other JavaScript mobile development frameworks like React Native and NativeScript-Vue do the bulk of their work on the mobile device, Svelte Native shifts that work into a compile step that happens when you build your app.
>
> Instead of using techniques like virtual DOM diffing, Svelte writes code that surgically updates the native view widgets when the state of your app changes.

this is from svelte-native official [web-site](https://svelte-native.technology)

so Svelte native is the name of the framework and that framework uses Nativescript.